# Check if language is decidable

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, undecidability, semi-decidability

I would like to determine if the following language is decidable or not.
L = { w $\in$ $\Sigma^*$ | $T(M_w)$ is recognized by a Turing machine with at most 42 states}.

I know that every finite language is decidable, but I am not sure if this has anything to do with this particular problem.

Every help is appreciated, I am a little lost.

Thank you

Comment: What is T(M)? Is it the language generated from the turing machine M?

Answer (score -1):

Define C = { $L | L$ is decidable by a turing machine with at most 42 states }

Notice that there is a finite amount of such languages, as there are a finite amount of turing machines with 42 states. for that reason, we have $C\ne\emptyset, \sum^*$

By Rice's theorem, the language $S=$ { $w | L(M_w) \in C$ } is undecidable. This language is precisely the language in question

Comment: Rice's theorem does not apply here.

Comment: Why? The conditions to it are obviously met